# Two Table problems with oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Students

```
ID  FName   Lname   Status      Major Code  GPA        Admitted Date        
104 Donald  Nento   Sophomore   105        2.64   1-Jul-2015
```

Departments

```
Dept Code   Dept Name   College
105         Mathematics   AS
```

These are the above tables... I am stuck on two questions:

4. List the college of the student with the highest GPA.
5. List Number of days elapsed since admission for each student.

Can anyone shed some light please?

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: They are review questions in my text for an exam.

Comment: We're happy to help students with homework questions.  But you're much more likely to get good assistance if you explain to us what you understand and what you don't understand and show us your current attempt.  For example, do you know how to calculate the number of days between two dates?  Do you know how to get today's date?  Do you know how to write a query that includes a calculation?  Not knowing that, it's hard to give you an answer that is more meaningful that "here's the code" which isn't what we try to do here.

Comment: Where is the foreign key in Students table to identify Department?

Comment: @JustinCave 

SELECT MAX(s.GPA), d.College,
FROM mytable1 s, mytable2 d
WHERE (THIS IS WHERE I'M LOST)
GROUP BY GPA;

Also, I have no idea how to format so this shows correct if someone could tell me that'd be great

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the CREATE TABLE statements for both tables?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggested queries. You'll need to adapt field names if they don't match. If you use double quotes the names are case sensitive, but if you have spaces in them, then you need to use double quotes:

> List the college of the student with the highest GPA.

```
SELECT     d."Dept Name"
FROM       Departments d
INNER JOIN Students s
        ON d."Dept Code" = s."Major Code"
WHERE      s.GPA = (SELECT MAX(GPA) FROM Students);
```

Or, if you are not allowed to use `INNER JOIN` then:

```
SELECT     d."Dept Name"
FROM       Departments d,
           Students s
WHERE      d."Dept Code" = s."Major Code"
      AND  s.GPA = (SELECT MAX(GPA) FROM Students);
```

> List Number of days elapsed since admission for each student.

```
SELECT     s.*, 
           TRUNC(SYSDATE) - s.Admitted_Date AS days_since_admission
FROM       Students s
```

Comment: Thank you sir.

I tried your first query, but have not discussed INNER JOIN yet, only OUTER JOIN.

Also, I tried it and got this error: "S" "Major_Code" invalid identifier.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to do it without `INNER JOIN`. 
For the names of the columns, you'll have to use the names exactly like they are in your database. I assume you can find that out. I have updated them to be like they appear in the titles you used in the example. But spaces in column names are tricky, it requires the use of double quotes, which also makes them case-sensitive. So please correct as needed.

Comment: Could you get back to us and give some feed-back? Did any of the answers help you out?

Answer (score 0):

> List the college of the student with the highest GPA.

You can get all the college(s) with the maximum GPA without using a correlated sub-query like this:

```
SELECT College
FROM   (
  SELECT College,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY GPA DESC ) AS gpa_rank
  FROM   Students s
         INNER JOIN
         Departments d
         ON ( s."Major Code" = d."Dept Code" )
)
WHERE gpa_rank = 1;
```

> List Number of days elapsed since admission for each student.

```
SELECT ID,
       FNAME,
       LNAME,
       FLOOR( SYSDATE - "Admitted Date" ) AS days_since_admission
FROM   students;
```

You could use `TRUNC(SYSDATE) - "Admitted Date"` but if the admitted date has a time component then it will not be a round number.

*(Note: it is unclear what your column names actually are. Your data shows them as case sensitive and with spaces but this is unusual as it is more usual to have case insensitive column names with underscores instead of spaces. I've used `""` to match the column names used in your post but please adjust the names to whatever the actual values are.)*